# How to do "something" when a window that is on background sends a specific message

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, window, wndproc

im trying to do something on an app, that I know its name etc...(so I'm alredy casting findwindow and stuff) 
For ex. I want to notify user when that window tries to gain focus.

I have mess around with wndproc yet I seem to not get it at all.
for ex. here is a code I found on stackoverflow and failed even executing it

```
    public IntPtr WndProc(int hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        if (msg == WM_NCACTIVATE)
        {
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

now the thing I dont understand is, there is int msg that I think stands for message. arent wndproc is the one that supposed to get it ? what is the point of giving it to wndproc ?

Second, executing this function. What do I do, check for message every 100 ms or are there event-type thing for it ?

Im really confused here and I'd appreciate little help here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I don't entirely understand what you're asking here.

That WndProc function definition that you've found is not what it would look like in C#. Instead, you would override the [`WndProc` member function of the `Control` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx). All window messages are routed through this function. You would only override it if you wanted to process a message in an unusual way, to do something that the .NET Framework isn't already doing for you.

For example, for a Form, you would override WndProc like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    // other code

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCACTIVATE:
            {
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                break;  
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);  // proceed with default processing
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the .NET Framework wraps all of the message information up into a [`Message` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.aspx), rather than passing 4 raw parameters to the function like the Win32 API does.

> there is int msg that I think stands for message. arent wndproc is the one that supposed to get it ? what is the point of giving it to wndproc ?

The [`Message.Msg` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.msg.aspx) corresponds to the `int msg` parameter in your function definition. This is the identifier of the window message that is to be processed. These are all defined inside of the Windows header files, and they generally begin with `WM_`. You can find the documentation for these messages on MSDN, which will tell you what they mean and when they are received. For example, the [`WM_NCACTIVATE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632633.aspx) is sent to a window when its non-client area is being activated or inactivated.

The WndProc function is going to be called *each time any message is received*. The way you determine *which* message was received, and therefore which one you should be processing, is by switching on the value of the `Message.Msg` member (or, in your original example, the `msg` parameter).

> Second, executing this function. What do I do, check for message every 100 ms or are there event-type thing for it ?

You don't have to check for anything. WndProc is a *function*, just like any other function, including those that you write yourself, which means that it only gets called when it should execute.

It is not itself an event, although the default processing inside of the WndProc function is what is responsible for raising the events you're familiar with in response to certain messages that it receives.

> im trying to do something on an app, that I know its name etc...(so I'm alredy casting findwindow and stuff) For ex. I want to notify user when that window tries to gain focus.

I'm not exactly sure what this means, but you should look into the [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614.aspx). This message is sent to a window whenever it is being activated and whenever it is being deactivated. In response to that message, you could choose to do whatever you like, including playing a sound. As the linked documentation indicates, the `wParam` parameter (found in the [`Message.WParam` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.wparam)) tells you whether your window is being activated or deactivated.

This is pretty much as advanced as it gets. It's extremely rare that you need to override the WndProc method when you're programming in WinForms. By doing so, you can do nearly anything, but there's almost always a better, simpler way to do things.